# Change focus on tab javascript imacros

Tags: javascript, imacros

This code is not working, how do i switch the focus on a tab. Is there another way?

```
var tabOne;
tabOne =  "CODE:";
tabOne +=  "TAB T=1";


iimPlay(tabOne);
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out...

```
var mainWindow = window.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIInterfaceRequestor)
.getInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIWebNavigation)
.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIDocShellTreeItem)
.rootTreeItem
.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIInterfaceRequestor)
.getInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIDOMWindow);

function TabLeft()
{
mainWindow.gBrowser.tabContainer.advanceSelectedTab(-5, true);
return "True";
}    
TabLeft();
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is:

```
var tabOne;
tabOne =  "CODE:";
tabOne =  "TAB OPEN"+"\n";
tabOne +=  "TAB T=2"+"\n";


iimPlay(tabOne);
```

OR

```
var tabOne;
tabOne =  "CODE:";
tabOne +=  "TAB T=1"+"\n";


iimPlay(tabOne);
```

I am interested to know what does your code do.

Comment: The **TAB T=** code doesnt work with javascript for some reason thats what i was saying in my original post, so the code i posted below is just a complicated way of moving the focus on the current tab to the left. The number **-5** in the code is the number of tabs it moves to the left.