# How to change focus on tabs using iMacros JS for Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, imacros

I have created a script using imacros javascript for firefox:

i want to create a function that can go and focus to the first tab, after opening the three tabs that are already working
I have try already some samples but can't figure it out how to do this

```
var macro;
var MyDelay;
MyDelay = Math.round(Math.random() * (5 - 2) + 2);

macro ="CLEAR"+"\n";
macro +="TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS"+"\n";
macro +="SET !ERRORIGNORE YES"+"\n";
macro +="SET !TIMEOUT 10"+"\n";
macro +="SET !TIMEOUT_PAGE 10"+"\n";

tabopen ="SET !ERRORIGNORE YES"+"\n";
tabopen +="SET !TIMEOUT 10"+"\n";
tabopen +="SET !TIMEOUT_PAGE 10"+"\n";
tabopen +="TAB OPEN"+"\n";

tab1 ="TAB T=1"+"\n";
tab1 +="SET !ERRORIGNORE YES"+"\n";
tab1 +="SET !TIMEOUT 10"+"\n";
tab1 +="SET !TIMEOUT_PAGE 10"+"\n";
tab1 +="URL GOTO=http://google.com"+"\n";
tab1 += "WAIT SECONDS=" + MyDelay + "\n";

tab2 ="TAB T=2"+"\n";
tab2 +="SET !ERRORIGNORE YES"+"\n";
tab2 +="SET !TIMEOUT 10"+"\n";
tab2 +="SET !TIMEOUT_PAGE 10"+"\n";
tab2 +="URL GOTO=http://google.com"+"\n";
tab2 +="WAIT SECONDS=" + MyDelay + "\n";

tab3 ="TAB T=-2"+"\n";
tab3 +="SET !ERRORIGNORE YES"+"\n";
tab3 +="SET !TIMEOUT 10"+"\n";
tab3 +="SET !TIMEOUT_PAGE 10"+"\n";
tab3 +="URL GOTO=http://google.com"+"\n";
tab3 +="WAIT SECONDS=" + MyDelay + "\n";

for (var i=1;i<50000;i++) {
    iimDisplay("Total: loop "+i+" here ");
    iimSet("i", i);
    iimPlayCode(macro);
    iimPlayCode(tab1);
    iimPlayCode(tabopen);
    iimPlayCode(tab2);
    iimPlayCode(tabopen);
    iimPlayCode(tab3);
}
```

and i renamed this script (woobi.js)

also have try `TAB T=1` but its not working

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change focus on tab javascript imacros](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27837578/change-focus-on-tab-javascript-imacros)

Comment: @Endless No is not a duplicate have try them and not working

Answer (score 0):

Does the script below work for you?

```
// open three tabs
iimPlayCode (
    "TAB OPEN" + "\n" +
    "TAB T=2" + "\n" +
    "WAIT SECONDS=1" + "\n" +
    "TAB OPEN" + "\n" +
    "TAB T=3" + "\n" +
    "WAIT SECONDS=1" + "\n" +
    "TAB OPEN" + "\n" +
    "TAB T=4" + "\n" +
    "WAIT SECONDS=1" + "\n"
);

// go to the first tab
iimPlayCode (
    "TAB T=-2" + "\n"
);
```